# Flutter & firestore: How to reference to an collection with auto generate id

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the value of a certain field of the document, let's say I have the value of 'eventName', and I wanna do update or delete the whole collection, how can I refer to the collection which is named with auto-generated id?

Also if it is possible to delete the whole collection or any way to similar effect?
[image: Database]

Comment: Firestore does not offer the capability to "update or delete the whole collection".  It only offers operations on documents.  You have to query for the documents you want  to work with, iterate the results of the query, and operation on each one individually.

Comment: I see, but then how can u get the reference to the collection generated if I only gave the value of the doc with in it?

Comment: Each DocumentSnapshot object contains a DocumentReference object, which contains a CollectionReference object for the parent collection.  Use the API documentation to see this.

Comment: @KentWong What exactly do you want to delete? Do you want to delete the document with id `r50d3...` or the collection `event` which contains 3 documents? Since you write "the collection which is named with auto-generated id" I have the feeling you are mixing-up collections and documents => In the screenshot of your database the only auto-generated ids are ids of Documents, not Collections.

Comment: Could you edit your question explaining what is exactly what you want to acomplish, while putting examples of what you mean by "the value of a certain field of the document" and "auto-generated id"?